# React Native: How to get upload speed and network signal strength?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am currently tasked with developing an application that gives the user various information and details about his network connection using React Native. The main issue is that I am unable to find a library or method to get the user's upload speed or signal strength.

I am using these libraries to get the download speed and network information:

react-native-network-bandwith-speed
@react-native-community/netinfo

These are working just fine.

I found many APIs that allow the integration of fast.com or speedtest.net, but these are not compatible with React Native.

The only thing(s) missing is the upload speed, and signal strength. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything you found on your end for upload speed and signal strength?
I am also looking for similar thing to implement in app.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I guess I will have to do this through a native android module, but I have yet to try that.